# How to use mouse hover in Capybara with ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I have tried the following in **Capybara** with **Selenium** but it did not work.

`find('#element').trigger(:mouseover)` 
or 
`page.find("#element").click` 
or 
`page.execute_script("$('#element').trigger('mouseover')")` 
or 
`find(:css,#element').hover` 
or 
`**capybara webkit**` 
one also i tried nothing worked.
Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
page.execute_script("$('#element').trigger('mouseenter')")
```

For a clean solution, you need to have `capybara-webkit` gem installed. In your spec_helper add:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ... Your configuration
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
end
```

With this you should be able to trigger events with:

```
page.find('#element').trigger(:mouseover)
```

Answer (score 0):

When nothing works, you can simulate what's going on behind the scenes.

Given my HTML (body)

```
<body>

    <div id="myHiddenDiv">
        <a href="to/home/">A (not visible) link I'd like to click on</a>
    </div>

</body>
```

Given my CSS:

```
div#myHiddenDiv
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
div#myHiddenDiv:hover
{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Without jQuery, without webkit (but with Selenium), I can do:

```
feature 'My div becomes visible' do

    scenario 'I can fake mouseover' do

        expect(page).not_to have_tag('div#myHiddenDiv', visible: true);

        # As if I mouseovered
        page.execute_script(<<-JS)
            let div = 'document.querySelector('div#myHiddenDiv');
            div.style.visibility = 'visible';
        JS

        expect(page).to have_tag('div#myHiddenDiv', visible: true);

        click_link("A (not visible) link I'd like to click on")

        # And go on!…

    end
end
```